# Javascript error with JSHint

Tags: javascript, node.js

I brought this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Full-Stack-JavaScript-Development-MEAN/dp/0992461251/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1424518897&sr=8-3&keywords=mean](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0992461251)

And I was studying the examples and came across with this piece of code:

```
var http    =   require(‘http’);
var fs  =   require(‘fs’);
http.createServer(function  (req,   res)    {
    if  (req.url    === ‘/favicon.ico’) {
            return  res.end();
    }
    console.log(‘Incoming   request to  ‘   +   req.url);
    var i   =   2;
    res.writeHead(200,  {‘Content-Type’:    ‘text/plain’});
    setTimeout(function()   {
            fs.readFile(__filename, {
                    encoding:   ‘utf8’
            },  function    (error, contents)   {
                    if  (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                            return  res.end();
                    }
                    console.log(‘sending    response    for ‘   +   req.url);
                    res.end(contents);
            });
    },  5000);
    while(i—)   {
            console.log(‘Loop   value:  ‘       +   i   +   ‘\r’);
    }
}).listen(1337, ‘127.0.0.1’);
console.log(‘Server running at  http://127.0.0.1:1337/’);
```

I found 3 problems:

- The programmer uses 2 spaces, which is common among beginning programmers (it has 8 spaces now because I changed it, it should be 4, I know)
- The code does not compile
- Bad programming practices, like "__filename", from where he got this variable from??

So as a new javascript programmer, I may be overextending myself and getting wrong conclusions. Is this the case?

These are the errors given by JSHint(npm install):

27,12: Unexpected '—'.

28,9: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 27 and instead saw 'console'.

28,16: Expected an identifier and instead saw '.'.

28,16: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

28,17: Missing semicolon.

30,1: Expected ')' and instead saw '}'.

30,2: Missing semicolon.

30,2: Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.

30,3: Expected an operator and instead saw '.'.

30,3: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

30,4: Missing semicolon.

So is this guy writing bad code in his book, or am I as a javascript beginning programmer overextending myself?

Comment: BTW two spaces is very practical in a book because typesetting.

Comment: He was using 2 spaces, but when I copy and pasted the code, it became 8 spaces, he did, or it just happens due the format translation between different documents?

Comment: No, it's because they were and still are tabs (see the source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because all of your `'` have been translated to typographical `‘` and `’`. A quick search and replace will fix it though.

Also, `i--` has been replaced with the ligature `i—`, fix that too. Try not to copy and paste code from books. Usually the source code is attached or downloadable from somewhere, but hand-typing is a good way for a new programmer to get familiar with a language.

As of the leading double underscore, there is no rule prohibiting it, and it's  usually a way to mark something as private (even a convention in languages like Python) or reserved.

Comment: Despite you being right about the code above, I already tried to change the ' and yet it does not work. Proof : http://imgur.com/zgiOeZV

Comment: I also tried to replace __filename with 'anyfile', yet jshint show the erros.

Comment: of course it shows, as it is not defined in the file. Set `__filename` as global

Comment: Ok @Stefano got it first. Thanks for all the input guys. He is right about the -- vs -... And the __filename he is right too, it was a global variable and the __ is used for private members. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, define it as a global for jshint: `/* global __filename*/`

Comment: When working with Node.js code, jshint provides a convenient `"node": true` configuration option that takes care of `__filename`, `__dirname`, `require` and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

This is working code. You just messed up with the formatting.

The `–` is `--` (might be converted as a ligature), the quotes are `‘` instead `'` and `__filename` is a global node variable (see [Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename)).

Fix the format errors and run the code, it's working:

```
> node app.js 
> Server running at  http://127.0.0.1:1337/
```